# OpenGL Android Extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch

Tags: android, c, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I want to use this GL extension on Android device, when call to glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS), the return string have "GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch", but my fragment shader:

```
#extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : enable
```

crashed, I confused..., how to make it right?

Comment: You'll need to show code so people understand the context.